# Ways to format time/duration in C# using short version

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan, duration

I'm looking for a way to format time duration originally expressed in hours (as a 'double' variable) for an ASP.NET web app written in C#. I need a short version that has only 2 significant values. For instance:

```
1h:20m
2d:20h 
2mo:12d 
5y:2mo
```

I searched and it seems like C# does not have a built-in function for what I need.

So I decided to write my own but I'm stumped with correct formatting of all the parts. For instance, I may get a string, such as "1d:24h", or for a simple 2 months, I may get "1mo:29d"

PS. The problem I've encountered is in defining how many days are in a month and in a year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime's are renowned for being an annoying task.

As there is no indication as to which months you are referring to, with the given information this would be impossible. Months can have 28, 29, 30 and 31 days depending on what month/year you are taking into consideration..

Without an indication as to which months you are dealing with, the flip from 1 to 2 months would be a random guess as to which day you make the transition. You will either have to add in more incoming parameters to account for this, or explain to the user that a month is considered x days and only x days.

Another thing to consider would be daylight savings. 1pm + 24 hours may not be 1pm the next day. In such circumstances with you or the end user may wish to consider such days 23h=1d or 25h=1d.

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I've been dealing with. You see, my task is to make a short representation that shows time duration (no connection to calendar months/years.) For instance, the task ran for: 1d:3h. So what is the accepted way of doing it?

Comment: Also, I dont think this kind of formatting give any benefit to end user, you may have to explain separately what means what.

Comment: if you just have to show the duration, you need time-stamp, bring the value in minutes (if it is ur smallest unit), at clinent side have separate labels(or span etc) with appended text like months, days, hours, minutes, calculate time stamp value and show these labels if they have values greater than 0. I mean basically instead of formatting them have separate variables/controls to show those values.

Comment: If you just receive an arbitrary number of days or hours etc, without a direct source of what the days represent the best you can do is guess. You'll have to go back to whomever gave you this spec and tell him it doesn't make sense in it's current state.

Comment: If you receive a date and specific time to run the calculation from then this would work however. Ask if a good assumption to make would be calculating it from the instance when the program is run. This would probably make most logical sense to the end user, however it would return different results to the same user input depending on when it was run.

Comment: I wouldn't go any further than days, eg it ran for 100 days, 3 hours. At which point you could look at the TimeSpan class.